# Mysql: Change charset to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to set up Confluence with docker-mysql. I have followed all instructions I could find on the net and Confluence is still giving me the `Your database must be configured to either use utf8 or utf8mb4 as the default character set.`

Here's my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
            - ./mycustom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    restart: always
    command: --sql_mode=""
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bachelorarbeit_database
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: horizon
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1P@ssw0rt123
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rt
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3310:3306'
```

Here's the `mycustom.cnf` that's in the same directory as the docker-compose

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_bin
default-storage-engine=INNODB
max_allowed_packet=256M
innodb_log_file_size=2GB
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
binlog_format=row
```

Here's the my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_bin
default-storage-engine=INNODB
max_allowed_packet=256M
innodb_log_file_size=2GB
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
binlog_format=row
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that by default, when creating a MySQL database with docker-compose, it defaults to latin1.

You can override that by passing the following command in your *db* service:

```
command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;' --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
```

I'm not sure what the `--sql_mode=""` is doing there is that just passing an argument to the default command? If so you'd probably add that to the list of arguments.

Once you've re-started your containers, you can login to the mysql one and running the following SQL to confirm it is now UTF-8:

```
mysql> SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8                     | utf8_unicode_ci      |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The `--sql_mode=""` is over writing default sql modes like Grou By, etc.